# jQuery slice div by nth interval per click?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to slice my divs in nth intervals per click. So for this example, each time I click, I want my function to slice the first three divs and hide them. And if I click again, then hide the remaining three divs.

```
$(document).on('click', '#dinner', function(){
var command = $(this).parents('#theworld');
var findpizza = command.find('.pizza');
for (var i = 0; i < findpizza.length; i+=3){
findpizza.slice(0, 3).hide();}
});
```

JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/crhggho5/

I do not want to use remove, as that makes hiding the div permanent. I also do not want to use `display:none` as that makes the div still visible, and it will do nothing after the first click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you tried to use a class to hide the div. This is what I would do. That way you can use the `.gone` class in your selector to exclude the ones that you have already hidden when the event listener is hit again:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dinner', function(){
    var command = $(this).parents('#theworld');

    //only get the slices that are not hidden
    var findpizza = command.find(".pizza:not('.gone')");

    for (var i = 0; i < findpizza.length; i+=3){
        //hide the slices via a class with 'display: none'
        findpizza.slice(0, 3).addClass('gone');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Create 2 indexes for tracking `sliceStart` & `sliceEnd`.

After every slice cycle set the `sliceEnd` to `sliceStart` index to seek the divs.

**JS CODE:**

```
var sliceStart = 0;
var sliceEnd = 3;
$(document).on('click', '#dinner', function() {
   var command = $(this).parents('#theworld');
   var findpizza = command.find('.pizza');
   if (sliceStart != sliceEnd) {
      findpizza.slice(sliceStart, sliceEnd).hide();
      sliceStart = sliceEnd;
      sliceEnd += sliceEnd;  
      return;
  }

  //detach the click event when job is done to 
  //avoid unnecessary event handling
  if (sliceStart === totalDivs) {
    $(document).off('click');
  }
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/crhggho5/1/)

*Note: FYI jquery `.hide()` internally sets the CSS style `disply:none` to the target element, so it is really not different from setting the CSS style `disply:none` manually to all the respective element*